# Alexa device settings API Error : 401 - "{"code":"ACCESS_DENIED","message":"Authentication failure with reason: TOKEN_INVALID"}

Tags: settings, alexa-skills-kit, access-denied

I have created a Alexa skill which I have given the skill developer access to other developers for testing.

In backend lambda code I am invoking Alexa settings API where it requires `deviceId` and `accessToken` as parameters.

Its working fine when I test the skill with my actual skill owner developer account but its throwing an error when other testers are trying to invoke the API.

> Error : 401 - "{"code":"ACCESS_DENIED","message":"Authentication failure with reason: TOKEN_INVALID"}"

Can you some one please help me here?

Comment: Did you get a solution to this problem? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Did you get a solution to this problem? I'm facing the same issue.